# How can i right-click on "ThisWorkBook" using applescript?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

How can I right-click on "ThisWorkBook" using applescript?

[[image: screenshot]]

I tried this code. But did not work.

Code to open VB Editor's project explorer window from Excel

```
tell application "System Events" 
    tell process "Microsoft Excel" 
        click static text 2 of group 1 of row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Project"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Great question.  I look forward to an answer.